# mouseover doesn't show hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, mouseover

```
<script>
$("#menu-item-58").mouseover(function() { $("#simple_sidenav-3").css('visibility','visible'); });
$("#menu-item-58").mouseout(function() { $("#simple_sidenav-3").css('visibility','hidden'); });
</script>

#simple_sidenav-3 {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

simple_sidenav-3 is a hidden div. 
So why doesn't it show when mouse is over #menu-item-58?

Please check it here http://mentor.com.tr/wp/?page_id=164

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `#simple_sidenav-3` from `visibility:hidden;` to `display:none;`  Then call something like `.slideDown()` for a nice effect.

Also, here's some improvements to your code:

```
jQuery(function() { //waits till the document is ready
    jQuery("#menu-item-58").mouseover(function () {
        jQuery("#simple_sidenav-3").slideDown();
    }).mouseout(function () {  //no need to use $("#menu-item-58") twice
        jQuery("#simple_sidenav-3").slideUp();
    });
});
```

Comment: display:none does something completely different.

Comment: It will do exactly what he is trying to do, and he can now use `.slideDown()` which will be a very nice effect for a rollover nav.

Comment: This is not about deciding what effects are "very nice" for someone else's website, this is about answering his question. setting the element to display:none will cause the element to disappear instead of just hiding it.

Comment: I provided my opinion. That's the beauty of stackoverflow. This might not be the exact answer he was looking for, but I think he would happier with the end result. Are we not supposed to give suggestions to users that might not know otherwise?

Comment: Thank you both for your answers, I prefer to use visibility. If I can't get it work I'll try it with display:none. Let me try your methods. Thanks again.

Comment: @Switz I decided to go with your method since I was able to add `delay()` to it before it slides up. Although I had to change `$` into `jQuery` to make it work. Thanks

Comment: No problem.  Glad to see you found a solution.  I would appreciate it if you hit the little check next to my answer.  Thanks!

Comment: I will once I have enough reputation :)

Comment: @Talha Accepting an answer can be done by everyone on the questions they have asked, regardless of reputation level.

Answer (score 3):

try this instead:

```
jQuery("#menu-item-58").mouseover(function() { 
  jQuery("#simple_sidenav-3").css('visibility','visible'); 
});
```

`$` is undefined.

Comment: jQuery.ready(function(){ -- I would assume. but I've kinda moved on. your problem definitely lies in the fact that $ is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't wrapped your code in the jQuery DOM ready function. Put this between your `<script>` tags:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#menu-item-58").mouseover(function() { $("#simple_sidenav-3").css('visibility','visible'); });
    $("#menu-item-58").mouseout(function() { $("#simple_sidenav-3").css('visibility','hidden'); });
}
```

This will bind the mouse events to the elements when the document (page) has been loaded.

Comment: hmm added that but still not visible.

Comment: @JamWaffles: You are half correct. Or even 1/3 correct ;) I mean according to [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3) this will be executed when the **DOM is ready**, not when the page finishes loading (there is some difference between these two events). But yes, it should be wrapped. Except `$` alias is not available and `$` is `undefined` on that page OP pointed - OP should use `jQuery` function instead of `$` function.

Comment: Thanks Tadeck. Would you know why `$` can't be used?